# How to change this class to function which has hooks in react.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Media } from 'reactstrap';

class Menu extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            dishes: [
                {
                  id: 0,
                  name:'Uthappizza',
                  image: 'assets/images/uthappizza.png',
                  category: 'mains',
                  label:'Hot',
                  price:'4.99',
                  description:'A unique combination.' },
        };
    }

render() {
    const menu = this.state.dishes.map((dish) => {
        return (
          <div key={dish.id} className="col-12 mt-5">
            <Media tag="li">
              <Media left middle>
                  <Media object src={dish.image} alt={dish.name} />
              </Media>
              <Media body className="ml-5">
                <Media heading>{dish.name}</Media>
                <p>{dish.description}</p>
              </Media>
            </Media>
          </div>
        );
    });

    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <Media list>
              {menu}
          </Media>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
}
}

export default Menu;
```

This is the piece of code which i learnt when starting react but react offered hooks and I can't seem to completely understand them yet and i need to convert this class to function. I want to be keeping up with the changes in technologies.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove your constructor and use react hook instead to manage state.

I recommend you to go through this for better understanding: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Media } from 'reactstrap';

function Menu (){
 
  const [dishes, setDishes] = useState({ dishes: [
    {
      id: 0,
      name:'Uthappizza',
      image: 'assets/images/uthappizza.png',
      category: 'mains',
      label:'Hot',
      price:'4.99',
      description:'A unique combination.' },
]} )

  

    const menu = dishes.map((dish) => {
        return (
          <div key={dish.id} className="col-12 mt-5">
            <Media tag="li">
              <Media left middle>
                  <Media object src={dish.image} alt={dish.name} />
              </Media>
              <Media body className="ml-5">
                <Media heading>{dish.name}</Media>
                <p>{dish.description}</p>
              </Media>
            </Media>
          </div>
        );
    });

    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <Media list>
              {menu}
          </Media>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
}


export default Menu;
```

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend reading the [official docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html).
But I'll explain a little bit.

Same as class components you have to import `react`.

If you want to use states in your component you should import `useState` too.

```
import React,{useState} from react
```

Then you just write a function like this

```
const yourComponent = (props)=>{
    //your code
}
```

The `props` in the function is similiar to `this.props` in classes

To render your `JSX` all you need to do is just simply return your `JSX` in your hook like:

```
const yourComponent = (props)=>{
    return (<div>Hello World</div>)
}
```

And to use states and methods you can do something like :

```
const yourComponent = (props)=>{
    const [count,increaseCount] = useState(0); //this will create a state named count with 
    value of 0
    const clickHandler = ()=>{
        insreaseCount(count+1) // and this will update the count state
    }
    return (<div onClick={clickHandler}>{count}</div>)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Media } from 'reactstrap';

const Menu = () => {
  const [dishes, setDishes] = useState([
    {
      id: 0,
      name:'Uthappizza',
      image: 'assets/images/uthappizza.png',
      category: 'mains',
      label:'Hot',
      price:'4.99',
      description:'A unique combination.' 
    }]); 

  const menuContent = () => {
    return dishes.map((dish) => {
      return (
        <div key={dish.id} className="col-12 mt-5">
          <Media tag="li">
            <Media left middle>
                <Media object src={dish.image} alt={dish.name} />
            </Media>
            <Media body className="ml-5">
              <Media heading>{dish.name}</Media>
              <p>{dish.description}</p>
            </Media>
          </Media>
        </div>
      );
    });
  }
  
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="row">
        <Media list>
          {menuContent()}
        </Media>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Menu;
```

Comment: Please practice explaining the answer instead of just leaving the code.